# How to bind java.net.MulticastSocket to localhost

Tags: java

I would like to bind a `MulticastSocket` to the address 127.0.0.1 (Socket should only be reachable within the current host) but with the following code example i got a

```
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: Datagram send failed exception
```

Is there a way to fix the problem? Here is my code

```
    int port = 6677;
    InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("232.0.1.10");
    try(MulticastSocket s = new MulticastSocket(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"),port))){

        String msg = "Hello";
        s.joinGroup(group);
        DatagramPacket hi = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(), msg.length(),group, port);
        s.send(hi);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Multicast is a little odd when compared to traditional UDP communication.  The whole point is to share data on a known "channel", simultaneously, to anyone who wants access.  This sharing is "signaled" to the network by using an IP address in the range 224.0.0.1 to 239.255.255.255.  If you try to bind to 127.0.0.1, you just aren't doing Multicast anymore.  And if you take a minute and think about it, that makes sense - you can't share the internal interface with other computers.

Comment: Other words: What you are trying to accomplish is in principle not correct. 'Multicast' is type of communication which is specified by a protocol. This requires IP address to be in some range, so network components win know 'oh yes, this is a multicast packet'. 127.0.0.1 is localhost = your computer. You cannot send multicast packets to your omputer.

Comment: I use Multicast for inter process communication. At the moment all processes are running on the same machine.

Comment: Does any body know how jgroups is doing it? It seems to be that they can bind multicast on a local machine. see http://www.jgroups.org/tutorial/ - 1.5. Using JGroups without a network

Comment: Multicast does not seem like the right mechanism for inter-process comms, especially on the same machine.  Without knowing anything about your app, I wonder if a pub/sub model using redis or some mqtt service (mosquitto?) would make more sense.